# Firebase Authentication with Flutter

Tags: flutter

Flutter Android Firebase authentication Error, The Authentication passes through but error in the terminal although the Application does not fail

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.

The Error seems to be coming from this Line of code

```
Future<String> currentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return user.uid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `_firebaseAuth.currentUser()` was null. Usually that means you are simply not logged in.

Before accessing the current user make sure that you log in.
For example using email credentials:

```
await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email:'email@here.com', password: 'abc123');
```

The good news is that the firebase package will cache the current user, so after you've logged in you don't have to do it again for a while, you can simply call your `currentUser` method.